# Subtle differences

Tags: meaning

I’ve been thinking a lot about these two sentences:

> I’ve **eaten** all the cookies
>   I’ve **been eating** all the cookies

What's the difference? Is the second one even correct?

Comment: I have eaten it's present perfect means the action happened before now in few minutes but I have been eating it's present continues perfect means the action happened in the past and happen now(you still eat)and it will happen in the future.

Comment: Yeah I know thet but I’ve been eating the cookies is what you’re talking about

Comment: I’ve been eating all the cookies is my question

Comment: The sentence doesn't make sense. "I have been eating cookies" describes an ongoing activity and doesn't say anything about the number of cookies left. You would have to say something like "I've been eating cookies all afternoon and now I've finished the whole tin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of at least one context in which "I've been eating all the cookies" is perfectly correct.

Let's say your roommate brings home cookies and you eat them all without telling your roommate. So the next day your roommate brings home cookies again and you eat them all again without telling them. The same thing happens the next day and finally your roommate says, 'Any idea what's going on? I've been bringing home cookies and before I can eat any they're all gone'. Then you say, 'Yes, I've been eating all the cookies.' because you have eaten all the cookies every time.

Another context where I've heard this, at least in American English, is when there are several different types of cookies - peanut butter cookies, chocolate chip cookies and oatmeal cookies. You are eating cookies and someone comes into the room and sees your plate. They ask, 'Have you only been eating the oatmeal cookies?'. You answer, 'No, I've been eating all the cookies'. The understood meaning here is that you've been eating all the different kinds of cookies, but people will often shorten it to 'I've been eating all the cookies' because the question is about one of the different kinds of cookies.

Idiomatically, people will also say this when they mean 'I've eaten a lot of the cookies.' or 'I've been eating cookies and I was going to eat all of them.'

To summarize, it doesn't seem like a grammatically correct construction but there are certain situations where it can be correct and several situations where people use it idiomatically.